# Fails for the testcase "([}}])" to validate expression(balancing parenthesis problem) which is coded in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

This code is written when I was trying to solve the problem on Leet code(the link to the problem is given below), which performs the balancing parenthesis but failing for the condition ([}}]) could anyone help me.

Thank you.

problem link---> https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

```
import java.util.*;

public class expressionValidation 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
 {
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in))/*trying to avoid any kind of exceptions*/
 {
                String str = sc.nextLine();
                String exp = "";/*new string  to modify the given expression*/
                int l = str.length();

                for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
{
                    if(str.charAt(i)=='{'||str.charAt(i)=='('||str.charAt(i)=='['||str.charAt(i)=='}'||str.charAt(i)==']'||str.charAt(i)==')')
{
                        exp+=str.substring(i,i+1);/*newly modified string afterstrong text removing everything except brackets'(' '[' '{' ' }' ']' ')'*/
                    }
                }   
                stack ob = new stack();
                System.out.println(ob.isValid(exp)?"Balanced":"NOT Balanced");
            }
        
    }
}
```

```
## The following is the stack class
```

```
class stack
{
    boolean isValid(String exp)
{
        int l =exp.length();
         if(l%2!=0)
                return false;
         Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
         for(int i=0;i<l;i++) 
{
             if(exp.charAt(i)=='{' ||exp.charAt(i)=='(' ||exp.charAt(i)=='[' ) {
                 st.push(exp.charAt(i));
             }
             else if(exp.charAt(i)=='}' && !(st.isEmpty()) && st.peek()=='{') {
                 st.pop();
             }
             else if(exp.charAt(i)==')' && !(st.isEmpty()) && st.peek()=='(') {
                 st.pop();
             }
             else if(exp.charAt(i)==']' && !(st.isEmpty()) && st.peek()=='[') {
                 st.pop();
             }
             String str = st.toString();
             System.out.println(str);
         }
        return st.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need a working solution? Because I had solved the leetcode problem.

Comment: in isValid method you are checking last parenthesis character is matching current parenthesis, but not updating boolean feild when condition fails

Comment: also need to check if stack is full or empty before push and pop operations

Comment: else if (ch == ')') {
  if (!sc.empty() && sc.peek() == '(') {
    sc.pop();
  } else {
     return false;
  }
 }

Comment: @BikkiMahato I would really appreciate that. Please share it if you approached it in the same way that I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My LeetCode submission :-

```
public boolean isValid(String s) {
    Stack<Character> sc = new Stack<>();
    for(int i =0;i<s.length();i++){
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(ch == '(' || ch == '{' || ch == '['){
            sc.push(ch);
        }else if(ch == ')'){
            if(!sc.isEmpty() && sc.peek() == '('){
                sc.pop();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else if(ch == '}'){
            if(!sc.isEmpty() && sc.peek() == '{'){
                sc.pop();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else if(ch == ']'){
            if(!sc.isEmpty() && sc.peek() == '['){
                sc.pop();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(sc.isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
boolean isValid(String s) {
    int max = s.length(), index = 0;
    char[] stack = new char[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        switch (c) {
        case '(': stack[index++] = ')'; break;
        case '[': stack[index++] = ']'; break;
        case '{': stack[index++] = '}'; break;
        default:
            if (index <= 0 || stack[--index] != c)
                return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you encounter `}` and the following condition fails

```java
else if(exp.charAt(i)=='}' && !(st.isEmpty()) && st.peek()=='{') {
```

you should already produce an error, but you just silently ignore the incoming `}` and continue the iteration. So all unpaired closing parenthesis/brackets are just silently removed from your input. Instead of `([}}])` you analyze `([])` which is a balanced string, so you get no error.

Same is true for other closing characters as well.